# Pandas python extra column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(output) 
df.to_csv('df.csv',mode='a')
```

This is my code and my output gives a row on top and column to the side of the appended parts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pass `index=False`:

```
df.to_csv('df.csv',mode='a',index=False)
```